Custom inspection boilerplate for Gosu/Guidewire
Does anyone have examples/boilerplate on custom intellij inspection for Guidewire?
I would like to extend SelectWithLimitingFunctionsInspection with first and single Called options, I can see that this is hardcoded in the inspection code itself.
This should be as simple as creating new jar file with the class implementing the same as SelectWithLimitingFunctionsInspection but with new Called options, then have inspections profile include that for CI runs. Did anyone do that already? I'm looking for confirmation that's the way and possibly project/setup for jar generation.
